# Why is my text file not overwriting after each execution?

Tags: java

My program reads in a text file, in.txt. That text file can have an arbitrary amount of lines.

My problem is that when I try to write to the output (out.txt) file, it appends it instead of overwriting.

The output file should have the same number as the input file.

```
    try {
        inFile = new Scanner(new File("in.txt"));

        while (inFile.hasNext()) {

        // Methods and stuff that doesn't matter...
        // Problem starts here

            try{
                outFile = new PrintWriter((new FileWriter("out.txt", true)));
                outFile.println(ArrayToString(intArray));                   
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.print("Could not find and write to the output file. " + e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                outFile.flush();
                outFile.close();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.print("Could not find the input file. " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The `ArrayToString` method returns a string to write.

EDIT:

I forgot to add this detail:

After reading the instructions again, I am not supposed to be creating a text file, just checking if it's there.

Comment: Since the latest edit i don't understand what the question is supposed to be about. Not certain I knew before but I'm totally stumped now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [the Javadoc for the FileWriter constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html):

> public FileWriter(String fileName,
>             boolean append)
>              throws IOException
>
> Constructs a FileWriter object given a file name with a boolean
>   indicating whether or not to append the data written.

Try setting the append flag to false. Then use the same writer instead of creating a new one each time through the loop (meaning that you should declare the FileWriter above the start of your while loop).

(Btw check out java.util.Arrays.toString, you shouldn't need to write your own code for this.)

Comment: I have tried that, but it only writes one line - the most recent result of the method.

Comment: @trama: understood, see if this is any better

Comment: After reading the instructions again, I am not supposed to be creating a text file, just checking if it's there.

Comment: If you want to see if a file exists, you just do something like File f = new File("/path/to/file.txt");  if ( f.exists() ) { // do something };

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
        try{
            outFile = new PrintWriter((new FileWriter("out.txt", true)));
            outFile.println(ArrayToString(intArray));                   
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.print("Could not find and write to the output file. " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Change the PrintWriter line to:

```
       outFile = new PrintWriter((new FileWriter("out.txt", false)));
```

Now, it looks like you're opening the file on every loop through your input file.  If you are wanting to open this file once, and write to it for each line in the input file, move the open and close outside the while loop like this:

```
    try {

    inFile = new Scanner(new File("in.txt"));
    // here we open the out file, once
    outFile = new PrintWriter((new FileWriter("out.txt", false)));

    while (inFile.hasNext()) {

    // Methods and stuff that doesn't matter...
    // Problem starts here

        try{
            // this will write a line to the out.txt file containing the intArray as a String
            outFile.println(ArrayToString(intArray));                  
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.print("Could not find and write to the output file. " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.print("Could not find the input file. " + e);
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
            inFile.close();
            outFile.flush();
            outFile.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
outFile = new PrintWriter((new FileWriter("out.txt", true)));
```

to

```
outFile = new PrintWriter((new FileWriter("out.txt", false)));
```

and

```
outFile.println(ArrayToString(intArray));
```

to

```
outFile.print(ArrayToString(intArray));
```